# Microsoft Access - "Search key cannot be found"

Tags: ms-access

Receiving error in title upon importing spreadsheet using import spreadsheet wizard.  Option "Let Access add primary key." was chosen, after clicking finish, error message saying "Search key cannot be found" pops up and spreadsheet is not imported.

Answer (score 1):

This issue typically occurs when you have leading spaces in the column headings of the Excel spreadsheet being imported.

Comment: several other posibilities too  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_other/access-2007-error-the-search-key-was-not-found-in/20785ff9-2004-40d7-9adc-71d2086ee5ff

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and it was due to a field in my access table that was "Long Text" and was Indexed. When I removed the Index, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue, I could not get the data to import, so I linked to the file instead.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34316237)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).